# GNU Make: Using the wildcard function with implicit rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu, unix-ar

I have a project structure that looks something like this:

```
.
└── src
    ├── Module1
    │   ├── source1.cc
    │   ├── source2.cc
    │   └── source3.cc
    ├── Module2
    │   ├── source1.cc
    │   ├── source2.cc
    │   └── source3.cc
    └── Module3
        ├── source1.cc
        ├── source2.cc
        └── source3.cc
```

I have an implicit rule that will create an object file for each source file, and maintain the directory structure (e.g. `src/Module1/source2.cc` would compile to `obj/Module1/source2.o`).

However, I would now like to have an implicit rule to create archive files for each module. For example, each object file compiled from `src/Module2` would be added to `obj/Module2.a`. My first idea looked quite similar to my implicit rule for object files:

```
obj/%.a: $(wildcard obj/%/*.o)
    @mkdir -p $(@D);
    ar -crs "$@" $^;
```

This would pass off the work of compiling the object files to the other implicit rule. However, the issue here is that the `%` character is not expanded.

Is there a way to access the `%` from the implicit rule within the wildcard function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
obj/%.a: $$(wildcard obj/%/*.o)
    @mkdir -p $(@D);
    ar -crs "$@" $^;
```